# How can I modify my html/jquery page fit to an android mobile screen?

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been looking for it online and everyone seems to refer to using "", but this doesn't seem to be working in my case, a friend asked me to make my website using jquery mobile but I feel there should be a way around this. Below are my html and css pages.

-html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Task 5 Report</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var act = [0,0];                    //added this

function resizeBoxes() {

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();

    $('#main').css({
        width: browserWidth*4,
        height: browserHeight*1,
        marginLeft: browserWidth*act[0]*-1,         //added this
        marginTop: browserHeight*act[1]*-1,         //added this
    });

    $('.box').css({
        width: browserWidth,
        height: browserHeight,
    });

}

resizeBoxes();

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeBoxes();
});


$('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    return false;
});

function goTo(horizontal,vertical) {

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();

    act[0] = horizontal;             //added this
    act[1] = vertical;               //added this

    $('#main').animate({
        marginLeft: '-'+browserWidth*horizontal,
        marginTop: '-'+browserHeight*vertical,
    }, 1000);

}


$('#link1 a').click(function(){
    goTo(0,0);
});


$('#link2 a').click(function(){
    goTo(1,0);
});

$('#link3 a').click(function(){
    goTo(2,0);
});

$('#link4 a').click(function(){
    goTo(3,0);
});



});

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">

<section id="box1" class="box">

<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>


    <h2>Kunal Matwani</h2>
    <h3>
This is a website with a portfolio of my work.<br> In this portfolio are the screenshots depicting my work with the android prototype.<br>
    </h3>
</section>
<section id="box2" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>


<h2>Big data</h3>
<p>
<ul class="contentul">
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
</ul>
</p>


</section>
<section id="box3" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

<h2>Server Side</h2>
<p>
This page contains all the information on the work done on the server side i.e MySql,Jetty etc. 
</p>

</section>
<section id="box4" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

<h2>Technical report</h2>
<p>
Attached is the technical report as required.
</p>

</section>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

-css

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* 
 * These selection declarations have to be separate
 * No text-shadow: twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 * Also: hot pink!
 */

::-moz-selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }


/* =============================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

a:hover, a:active { outline: 0; }

/*=========================================
    Main Styles
=========================================*/
body {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 54px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

h3 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.contentul {
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
color: #ffffff;
}

/*=========================================
    Nav bar
=========================================*/
nav {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
height: 50px;
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
line-height: 50px;
display: block;
}

/*=========================================
    Nav links
=========================================*/
#link1 {
background: #1691BE;
}

#link2 {
background: #166BA2;
}

#link3 {
background: #1B3647;
}

#link4 {
background: #152836;
}





/*=========================================
    Styling each section
=========================================*/
.box {
float: left;
}

#box1 {
background: #1691BE;
}

#box2 {
background: #166BA2;
}

#box3 {
background: #1B3647;
}

#box4 {
background: #152836;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the one page and CSS to fit a mobile screen as well as a desktop without using different code?

Comment: Ya that was the plan,is this possible?

Comment: Cool :) Totally possible - see my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a website that you are creating and want a user to view it on a mobile look at bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a concept called Responsive Design. This means your CSS and HTML adapt to fit the device they're being displayed on. So you can open the same website in a phone browser and on a giant desktop display and they will both work. That is, the content will be comfortably viewable on both devices.

This page will explain everything you need to know about it:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/designing-for-a-responsive-web--webdesign-3850

But if you want to just jump in then you can use a framework like Bootstrap as the other guy here said. There are loads of frameworks and some are really lightweight while others are full of features. Bootstrap is probably the most famous (and therefore most generic). You should have a look around and try a few different ones.

Still have a read of the tutorial though so you can understand how the grid systems work.